# Getting Full Exception Trace for Silverlight 5 WCF Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight

I've got a Silverlight 5 RIA with some WCF services built-in as part of the solution.

During the application run time, I get the following (rather generic) fault:

```
at NetVisSolution.AFDiscoveryService.AFDiscoveryServiceClient.OnGetChildrenElementsFromParentCompleted(Object state)
Caused by: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
```

I wish to get some more detailed exception code.

The following article seemed promising at first:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlightws/archive/2008/04/06/getting-full-exceptions-in-silverlight-2-beta-1.aspx

Manually editing assemblies is something I want to avoid if possible, unless there is a really foolproof method that doesn't involve tweaking public key tokens and the like.

Can anyone suggest a viable plan?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this :

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

and
see this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee844556(v=vs.95).aspx
and

Comment: The given xml snippet was already implemented, and _should_ work. However it doesn't for some reason. Are there any other prequisites? (Note that I want to throw an Undeclared fault).